# jQuery : passing concatenated id into selector weired situation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery DatePicker to select elements with '#', everything is working fine when i put "direct" string in the selector, but once i begin concatenating, the result is very suspicious.
Maybe this console screenshot explain what i am struggling with
[image]

HTML :

```
<input id="wizard:wizard-body:datePiece_picker" name="wizard:wizard-body:datePiece_picker" type="text" value="">
```

Javascript :

```
function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp(find, "g"), replace);
}
var TYPEDIALOG = "wizard:wizard-body:";

var id = replaceAll(TYPEDIALOG, ":", "\\\\:")+ "datePiece_picker";
if ($("#" + id).length != 0) {
    $("#" + id).datepicker({
        dateFormat : "dd/mm/yy"
    });
}
```

Comment: Where your related code ?

Comment: can you share the input html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your replace was adding too many backslashes:

http://jsfiddle.net/BaypN/

```
var id = replaceAll(TYPEDIALOG, ":", "\\:") + "datePiece_picker";
```

As a side note, this is probably a pretty good argument for avoiding `:` in element ids. Also, `datePiece_picker` could be a class instead of part of the id.

Comment: awesome, I was doing like that but i can't realise why that didn't work in the first time, thanks again
PS : for the ":", it is an old JSF page